# HTML embedded base64 png image fails to decode

Tags: html, css, base64

I'm attempting to customize the webUI of a Tasmota binary for an espressif based device.  My goal is to embed a base64 encoded PNG into the main page so that the image is available even if the internet connection is unavailable.

I have converted a sample image to base64 via CLI as well as several online converters, and have validated the base64.  if I plug the data URI into my browser, the image renders correctly, but if I compile the binary and flash the device to view the page, I receive an error and a broken thumbnail.

my current image is

```
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
```

and my insertion is

```html
"<img src='data:image/png;charset=utf-8;base64,**base64string**'>"
```

which I have tried both with and without specifying charset, I've tried inserting my code within or around div and p tags...

this webserver is contained within a .ino which I am compiling with platformio, hence the outer " " and the inner ' '
safari is reporting: Failed to load resource: Data URL decoding failed

when I view the source, I see

```html
<img src='data:image/png;charset=utf-8;base64,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</div><div id=' l1' name='l1'>
```

it's clearly not pulling all of the base64 or truncating it. I'm counting 799 characters in the browser debug of the base64 string, despite the full length of the string is 5168 characters. additionally, safari is complaining about    `eb('l1').innerHTML = s;` citing "null is not an object" and I've no idea what that means or where's coming from.

I'll be the first to admit that I have a tenuous grasp of HTML, even less of CSS, and even less of web language contained within a .ino

happy to receive any pointing in any direction, if this is too big of a can of worms to digest.

oh, also I suppose it's possible to enable SPIFFS and just host the .png on the device's filesystem, but I'm probably even further away from understanding how to implement that.  if that's easier, I'm more than willing to go down that road.

Flash size is 1M and binary is currently 602K, so there is some room left.

source code available at https://github.com/arendst/Tasmota/releases/
Tasmota v9.2.0

EDIT:
I have created a 5px x 5px (and consequently 1px x 1px) test image, and same issue.  if I load the page and debug, I see the error.  If I edit the source html and paste the correct code and close the ", the image then loads.

the browser shows:

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div id=" l1'="" name="l1">
```

I can see that the base64 is truncated, and the SRC URL is no longer closed by a second set of ".  if I manually insert the closing " paste the remainder of the code into the source, the image then renders.

it looks like something in the string (or perhaps a length restriction in the webserver.ino is breaking this?

Comment: This is not your main problem, but on the secondary one (l1) there seems to be a space in the id of the div following your img. Is that meant? in 'ordinary' HTML an id cannot contain a space.

Comment: Can you try with an absolutely tiny base64 png image - just to assure ourselves that all the surrounding HTML is OK - given there does seem to be that problem with the id immediately following.

Comment: I have tried without space, and in my googling I saw examples with space. Both ways; same result/fail.  I tried resizing test image down to 20% of original size, but I will try a minuscule dot next, that’s a great idea thanks

Comment: Oh I misunderstood. The space in the div tag, not sure how it’s there. It’s not in the source

Comment: Sorry for triple-tap, but I will also add, if I remove the base64 and call external png with img src, the code does not error. I suspect the base64 string is causing issue

Comment: original question updated with new information